# Next dev or Next build doesn't keep running stops automatically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

Basically I'm trying to run the latest version of Nextjs (13.4.4) with Node Version v18.16.0 and it just stops without any error message,

[image]

Same happens with `next build` command, also, i tried with Yarn resulting in the same output, yarn version being 1.22.10

Also, for some reason, this doesn't happen with Nextjs version 13.0.0

I've tried everything, from changing node versions, to deleting caches, nothing works

I've tried everything, from changing node versions, to deleting caches, nothing works

my package.json is:
`{ "name": "nextjs", "version": "0.1.0", "private": true, "scripts": { "dev": "next dev", "build": "next build", "start": "next start", "lint": "next lint" }, "dependencies": { "eslint": "8.41.0", "eslint-config-next": "13.4.4", "next": "13.4.4", "react": "18.2.0", "react-dom": "18.2.0" } }`